# Is there only one servlet object per tomcat server?

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I did a simple test, and executed my test servlet below from different browsers and command line tools. Regardless where I execute it, it displays the same "hohoho time". I am absolutly fine with this, I just want to know two things:

a) if I can rely on this on different versions of tomcat (today I use version 7.54)

b) does this mean a servlet is never executed parallel in different threads (i.e. two users are requesting the very same servlet at the very same time)

```
@WebServlet(name="test servlet 2", urlPatterns={"/test2"}, loadOnStartup=1)
public class Test2 extends HttpServlet {
    private String test = "baaa .. :-(";

    @Override
    public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
        DEBUG("Server starts");
        this.test = "hohoho " + System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) throws ServletException, IOException {
        ServletOutputStream out = resp.getOutputStream();

        out.write(test.getBytes());

        out.flush();
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have below view on your question.

**a**) Yes,atleast from tomcat 7 onwards.For tomcat 6(`annotation support`),you will have to check the specs.

**b**) Regarding execution in parallel thread,servlet not threadsafe by default,to ensure thread safety,Servlet service() method should not access any member variables, unless these member variables are thread safe themselves.

For more on thread safety : [Servlet Thread Safety](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2072798/java-web-development/write-thread-safe-servlets.html)

Answer (score 1):

Indeed servlet container creates only one instance of each servlet. This helps you to hold state in servlet member variables. This however does not mean that servlet container cannot use the same servlet instance to process serveral requests simultaneously. This is what servlet contains (including Tomcat) does. Therefore your servlet must be thread safe. Please refer to this article for details: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-servlets/servlet-concurrency.html

Answer (score 0):

There is only one instance of each HttpServlet and its init() method is only called once when the HttpServlet is constructed. However the doGet() is called in a different thread for each request and can happen in parallel.